# How to store files in a binary tree struct and then output them

Tags: c, struct

I have the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};

/* newNode() allocates a new node with the given data and NULL left and
 right pointers. */
struct node* newNode(int data)
{
    // Allocate memory for new node
    struct node* node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    node->data = data;

    // Initialize left and right children as NULL
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    return(node);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    printf("You Typed the following %s", argv[1]);

    /*create root*/
    struct node *root = newNode(1);
    /* following is the tree after above statement
     1
     /   \
     NULL  NULL
     */

    root->left        = newNode(2);
    root->right       = newNode(3);
    /* 2 and 3 become left and right children of 1
     1
     /   \
     2      3
     /    \    /  \
     NULL NULL NULL NULL
     */

    root->left->left  = newNode(4);
    /* 4 becomes left child of 2
     1
     /       \
     2          3
     /   \       /  \
     4    NULL  NULL  NULL
     /  \
     NULL NULL
     */

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

which generates a binary tree in memory. My plan is to load pointers of files into the "nodes" of the tree. The files would come from command line arguments

Then based on user input I would like to go left (or right) in the tree and when a node is hit it should print out the file content and so on...

How can I do that
Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You're getting ahead of yourself - you should finish off implementing the binary tree code - like making a function that adds a node to the tree, rather than doing it manually like you are currently - especially as you're not adding the nodes in the correct order.

Comment: "How can I do that" - by writing code.

Comment: Also, no not cast the return value of `malloc`, no parentheses needed for `return`.